# How can I use "uri"

Tags: android, uri

I have an image and I want to use it in another class. So I create a URI like that:

```
final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String path = selectedImage.getPath();
Intent sintent = new Intent(FromFile.this, OurView.class);
sintent.putExtra("image", path);
startActivity(sintent);
```

I called uri like that in the class of OurView

```
String ur = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
try {
    URI uri = new URI(ur);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to use this picture as a background in this class. How can I do that?

Comment: Be careful: URI and Uri are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, we have Activities. It seems like you want to set the image as the Activity's background. To do this, you have to set it as the background in your parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass URI to intent rather than passing the path. It will take as Parceable Value in putExtra

```
final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
Intent sintent = new Intent(FromFile.this, OurView.class);
sintent.putExtra("image", selectedImage);
startActivity(sintent);
```

And then

```
URI ur = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
```